Can an Italian travel to Italy and back to the UK with less than 3 months on an Italian passport?
My husband holds an Italian passport and has settled status in the UK, we are travelling to Italy in August for 2 weeks and his passport expires in October. He has been unable to renew it before we travel and the consulate advised him that he can travel to Italy right up to the expiry date if necessary and that he should be able to re-enter the UK as he has settled status and has lived here for over 18 years. We have also asked the airline and they've said it "should" be ok. But I am nervous, is this right? I am wondering if there is anything documents we can print off that proves this, in case there is someone who doesn't know this loophole if indeed it does exist

I looked it up for the Netherlands to UK and there it is (also) up to expiry date of the passport, even without settled status. I post as a comment and not an answer as it is a different country.

To go to Italy there is no doubt that he can use his passport (or national ID card) up to very last day. The other way around I have no idea, but check https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ and https://www.traveldoc.aero/ with your actual details. If those say OK there shouldn’t be an issue, as airlines use one of those to determine eligibility (unless maybe it’s Ryanair as they like to invent rules which do not exist).

This EU page states that those with Settled status can enter the UK with a valid passport or identity card. Try putting the trip details, passport data etc into IATA. If that returns a positive answer you’re probably good.

I would assume that any document (even an expired one) allows you to enter Italy as italian citizen. At least in Switzerland that's a basic citizen right, and so the immigration office clearly says that you can enter with anything that proves your identity, including an expired passport.
